# What is the term used to describe a person explaining a movie plot scene by scene?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

Let's say I watched a movie and would want to read about it in a textual form. So it would involve someone describing scenes of movie in the order that they were telecasted.

What term should I search on Google to get to that page? Something like "[movie name] plot summary" or "[movie name] synopsis" or "[movie name] summary" didn't seem to get the desired result.

I'm looking for something exactly like this [Game of Thrones S06E10](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/The_Winds_of_Winter) which explains the episode scene by scene.

Comment: In the title, you ask for a term to describe a *person*.  In the question you seem to be asking for the name of a summary - or for a search term. Please be specific what it is precisely that you want. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be looking for **Treatment**: A scene by scene description of a screenplay, minus all or most of the dialogue.

The scriptwriter will probably write the treatment along with the screenplay.

[Screenwriting.info: Glossary](http://www.screenwriting.info/glossary.php)

Comment: Pretty close. But that's more like a transcript. I was looking for something like the example I provided in my OP, kinda link a theoretical description.

Comment: @asprin - That's the one!

Answer (score 1):

Narration/narrative? That's what blind people get when they watch a movie with the screen-reader on.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, you are asking for a suitable search term. Here's my first try:

[**groundhog day plot synopsis**](https://www.google.co.uk/search?sxsrf=ALeKk00o1HNjpBfoEeXQJEG4IB92mgmhDg%3A1610036818616&source=hp&ei=Ujb3X9zDIsXlgweZ-53gAw&q=groundhog+day+plot+synopsis&oq=groundhog+day+plot+synopsis&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQDDIFCAAQyQNQvhNYvhNgjiBoAHAAeACAAUOIAUOSAQExmAEAoAECoAEBqgEHZ3dzLXdpeg&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwjctJXFnoruAhXF8uAKHZl9BzwQ4dUDCAk)